# Matlplotlib with Qt backend on OS X -> Incompatible library versions

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I'm having some problems with `matplotlib`'s OSX native backend, namely that plot windows always pop up on the background. 
I wanted therefore to try `matplotlib`'s `Qt` backend, but when I try it I get the     following error message:

```
ImportError:
dlopen(/Users/x/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so,
2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib   Referenced from:
/Users/x/anaconda/lib/libQtGui.4.8.7.dylib   Reason:
Incompatible library version: libQtGui.4.dylib requires version 39.0.0
or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 38.0.0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever comes across this problem, my solution was to:

```
brew uninstall libpng
brew cleanup && brew prune
brew install libpng
```

and

```
conda clean --all
conda update --all
```

Now matplotlib works fine with Qt backend.

Comment: My problem was that there were too many libpng installed in my system, and apparently an older one was shadowing a newer one. Try to find out what libpng your python is seeing. I can't remember the details of how I sorted that out. I should've documented it with my answer..

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by manualy removing `libpng16.16.dylib` and other versions of `libpng` from `~/anaconda/lib` and then installing latest version with brew

```
brew install libpng
```